# Check if a date in an index matches the date of a cell

Tags: google-sheets, match, google-sheets-formula

[image: Image for clarification]

I have this spreadsheet which is a Cash Flow and the payments vary from monthly, quarterly, every 6 months and so on. When it comes to payments every x months, I'm having trouble creating a formula to check if the amount should be added to x month, for example:

I have columns with each month of the year:

```
01-2021 | 02-2021 | 03-2021 | 04-2021 | 05-2021 | 06-2021...
```

Then I made a separate table to calc when the amounts should be added, which equals to the start month and year, then that day + 6 months (in the case of payments every 6 months) and so on:

```
Start date: 01-2021
Value: $100

First payment: 01-2021

Second payment: 07-2021

Third payment: 01-2022
...
```

And the amounts of this specific case should be added under the respective months ($100 under 01-2021, another $100 under 07-2021, another $100 under 01-2022...)

I've made a INDEX(MATCH)) that returns all the payment dates based on the "start date", but how can I check they match the dates of the first table mentioned?

```
IF(date_from_table = any of the dates in the array, amount, 0)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on, free of sensitive information?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't, but I uploaded an image with an example that pretty much reflects what I need to do, if that's of any help.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
VLOOKUP(date_from_table, dates in the array and amount, amount, exact match)
```

---

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, Sheet1!A:B, 2, 0)))
```

Comment: Couldn't figure out what you meant. I added an image to perhaps make the issue clearer.